# JavaScript - Wondering how to add html elements

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code:

```
var add, substract, multiply, divide;
var calculation = {
    add: {
        place: 2,
        name: add,
        calculation: function (a,b) {return a + b;},
        output: function (a,b) {return a + ' + ' + b;},
        buttonHTML: '+'
    },

    substract: {
        place: 2,
        name: substract,
        calculation: function (a,b) {return a - b;},
        output: function (a,b) {return a + ' - ' + b;},
        buttonHTML: '-'
    },

    multiply: {
        place: 1,
        name: multiply,
        calculation: function (a,b) {return a * b;},
        output: function (a,b) {return a + ' * ' + b;},
        buttonHTML: '*'
    },

    divide: {
        place: 1,
        name: divide,
        calculation: function (a,b) {return a / b;},
        output: function (a,b) {return a + ' / ' + b;},
        buttonHTML: '/'
    },
};
document.getElementById("calculator").innerHTML=('
for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
    var btn = document.createElement ("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode (i);
    btn.appendChild(t);

};');
```

In my html file the script is loaded in the head elements. In body I have a div element named calculator.   Now what I want to do is to create buttons inside of that div element with the loop I have. But what I have written seems to not work and I fail to find any better solution too.  Any ideas?

Comment: innerHTML can only be a string. you're adding something that looks like a mixture of a closure and a string and doesn'T really exist.

get rid of the `document.getElementById("calculator").innerHTML=`part and place the rest of the code inside a function that gets called on `window.onload`.

Comment: But how do I make the window.onload use the function in the div element?

Comment: I basicly load the script in the <head> tags.  Div tags are in the <body> tags.  Div id is calculator and I want to make it so that the script will find the div and put the buttons inside of it.

Comment: Why not write the buttons directly into the calculator Div? Why do you want to use a script to create them?

Comment: It's an assignment I have to make the whole calculator as an object so that it would be possible to make multiple calculator appear on the screen when needed.

Comment: you're assigning a string to innerHTML. That wont evaluate the function. Albeit, it will just assign the string as the nodes content.

Comment: @gprasant Actually assigning a string to `innerHTML` DOES work. Only that string is just displayed as text inside that element then.

Comment: @JohannesH. yes, sorry if I was unclear. I meant - it wont do what you're expecting it to do in the current context .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that creates the buttons looks fine to me. The only thing is: it's not a function, and it doesn't get executed anywhere. Instead, it's assigned as a string to `innerHTML`. That won't work. Instead, use this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("calculator").appendChild(btn);
    } 
};
```

Comment: No problem ;) Hope you didn't just take it but you also understood why your approach was wrong and how this works?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the numbers 0 to 9   the following function will add the required buttons inside a div with a known id. It will not necessarily position them as you need nor get them to respond as you require but it should get them into the div.

```
function insertNumberButtons(id) {
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```